# Bitwise operators in Lua for Windows?

Tags: windows, lua, bitwise-operators, xor

I am currently using Lua for Windows, and my current project deals with binary files. I need the XOR bitwise operator however, I don't think Lua for Windows have a bitwise operator library since it's still version 5.1 (a bitwise operator library was added in 5.2). Is there a way to get bitwise operators in Lua for Windows (version 5.1)?

Thanks!

Comment: [There are tons of them.](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BitwiseOperators) First hit for "Lua bitwise operator library" search on Google, which should always be your first stop before StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LuaBitOp](http://bitop.luajit.org/) is included with Lua For Windows, so you just need to add

```
require 'bit'
```

at the top of your program.